# How do I stop (postgres.app) postgres cluster from command line

Tags: postgresql, terminal, postgres.app

How do I stop a particular Postgres.app cluster without using the gui.

Instead of gui, I want to use bash/Terminal.app

[image: stopping it via gui]

I should also point out that, Postgres app has a menu like this

[image]

So if I do a `kill`, would the menu show an incorrect state?

Comment: You can do this using `pg_ctl`. First, get the `pid` of your cluster using `pg_ctl status -D <path to postgres data dir>`, this will give you the `pid` eg. `server is running (PID: 1143)`. Next, kill the process using `pg_ctl kill ABRT 1143`.

Comment: I figured kill is not the best answer, because Postgres app wouldn't know about it, so it would not show up in the top menu where it shows which clusters are running.

Comment: Then how about `pg_ctl stop -D <path to postgres data dir>`

Comment: @Isank, I have verified and that command does work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done using `pg_ctl`

`pg_ctl stop -D <path to postgres data dir>`

Example

`pg_ctl stop -D ~/Postgres/pg96/data`